# How to find bitcoin balance via command line

Tags: full-node, bitcoin-cli

I'm wondering how to find the balance a wallet for a full node on a command-line only linux box.  `bitcoin-cli` doesn't seem to help here, and I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple RPC call `getbalance`. So `bitcoin-cli getbalance` should give you the number.

Comment: When I try `bitcoin-cli getbalance` I get
`error: {"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found"}`

Comment: That means your bitcoind is compiled without wallet support.

Comment: how about how to get balance of another public address?

Comment: Bitcoin Core has no support for querying the balance of an address individually. You can add the addresses you care about to a wallet using `importaddress` or `importmulti`, and then query the wallet's balance after rescanning.